# Does server running on local host constitute IoT?

Tags: networking, microcontrollers, aws-iot, cloud-computing, deployment

I have created a network, using mobile hotspot (without internet connectivity), between microcontroller and pc.(intranetwork) The designed server right now works on the local host. Will this be considered IoT or only after deploying it on cloud and assigning an ip (making it remotely accessible) it will be called IoT?

Comment: Unfortunatly, I think this is an entirely subjective question, unless you can claboarate on why you care. If you are asking if it is work you can ask about here, yes maybe (but that would be a meta question, and you can ask for it to be migrated).

Comment: Hii this is one project I have done where I have transmitted sensor values to database and stored them. I have performed certain analysis over it and displayed it on a web page. But currently this webpage is accessible only on local host that is my pc. Some advised to take this on cloud and others say it is fine. The whole thing is IoT. I just want to know will taking the server on the cloud, make it IoT? or it is still IoT?

Comment: IoT is just a word, like blockchain.

Comment: So is internet connectivity must in an IoT project?

Comment: Where did anyone say that?

Comment: To me, IOT is more about connectivity, automation, and some central control than "internet" per se. You can consider "Intranet Of Things" as "IOT", and that's actually a real term anyway.

Comment: Ok so what I have created is intranet of things. I also read that intranet is also sometimes accessible to internet, but with certain restrictions such as limited number of users or traffic.

Answer (score 1):

One man’s Mede is another man’s Persian. How long is a piece of string? Since there is no agreed or standardized definition of “Internet of Things”, your question

> Will this be considered IoT

begs the question

> by whom?

I say potato, Dan Quayle says potatoe, let’s … just agree that it depends on the point of view of the questioner and move on to implementing something :-)